# Make progress bar dynamic depending on conditions of record Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a progress bar that changes its inner width depending on the conditions met in my `Campaign` instance.

**In my view**

```
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= progress(campaign) %> %"></div>
```

**I'm trying to make a helper method to make this:**

```
  def progress(campaign)
    @count = 0
    if c.paid?
        @count += 25
    end
    if c.logo_design.present?
        @count += 25
    end
  end
```

**It's not working (conditions are met).**

Can someone iluminate me on how is this approach done?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried returning `@count` at the end? Also, you've got a space before the "%" sign in the style, so you end up with `width: 25 %`, which I think is not valid CSS.

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the aria-valuenow attribute instead I guess

```
<div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%= progress(campaign) %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%= progress(campaign) %>%"></div>
```

Comment: Still not working, I tried to inspect progress and it returns 25 :/

Comment: @user3074558 try the updated answer, it seems you have to set both valuenow and css width